# Miners don't detect ASIC Devices

Tags: client, miner-configuration, asic, bfgminer

When I try to add devices to BFGMiner and BitMinter, Only 3/4 devices will be detected, When I go to Devices and Printers (In Windows 7) it shows all of my ASIC Miners.

Here is the error:

```
2014.02.26 [19:09] BitMinter Client v1.4.3 started 
2014.02.26 [19:09] Found 1 OpenCL-compatible GPU 
2014.02.26 [19:09]  Hint: Use performance mode for best GPU results (bottom right button) 
 2014.02.26 [19:09] Probing all ports for external devices 
2014.02.26 [19:09]  Probe of port COM16 failed: timeout 
2014.02.26 [19:09] No external devices detected. 
2014.02.26 [19:09] Device detected on COM15: Icarus 
2014.02.26 [19:09]  Icarus detection on COM3 failed. Expected nonce 0x00000109 but got 0x3F3F3F09. 
2014.02.26 [19:09] Device detected on COM3: Icarus 
2014.02.26 [19:10]  Icarus detection on COM17 failed. Expected nonce 0x00000109 but got 0xFFFFFFFF. 
2014.02.26 [19:10]  Icarus detection on COM17 failed. Expected nonce 0x00000109 but got 0xFFFFFFFF. 
2014.02.26 [19:10]  Probe of port COM17 failed: timeout 
2014.02.26 [19:10]  Error reading from COM17: File descriptor is -1 < 0, maybe closed by previous error condition 
2014.02.26 [19:10] Device detected on COM16: Icarus
```

How can I get the miners to detect all the devices. The devices are on COM 3, 17, 19, and 20

Thanks,
Bgordy

Comment: what kind of asic miner? block erupters?

Answer (score 2):

You are likely running into power limits. Your USB hubs must be powered properly, able to supply the full current all of these devices need to operate.